# Simple filtering by date and user who created the event

Tags: python, google-api, filtering

How would I filter all events by the user who are the attendees but not the creator of the event(email) and only the current month's events. So start date this month to end date this month last day.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events

```
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=CAL_ID, maxResults=2500).execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    for e in events:
        print(e)
```

An example result:

> [{'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"-', 'id': '-', 'status':
> 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': '-', 'created': '2022-01-12T04:06:25.000Z',
> 'updated': '2022-01-16T20:47:31.134Z', 'summary': 'First day',
> 'description': 'This is just here as a placeholder', 'creator':
> {'email': 'x@hotmail.com'}, 'organizer': {'email':
> '-@group.calendar.google.com', 'displayName': 'HerokuApp', 'self':
> True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-01-11T02:30:00-08:00', 'timeZone':
> 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-01-11T03:30:00-08:00',
> 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'iCalUID': '-@google.com',
> 'sequence': 0, 'reminders': {'useDefault': True}, 'eventType':
> 'default'}, {'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"-"', 'id': '-',
> 'status': 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': '-', 'created':
> '2022-01-12T04:15:09.000Z', 'updated': '2022-01-16T20:48:08.061Z',
> 'summary': '2nd', 'description': 'Testing sort', 'creator': {'email':
> '@hotmail.com'}, 'organizer': {'email': '-@group.calendar.google.com',
> 'displayName': 'HerokuApp', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime':
> '2022-01-11T04:00:00-08:00', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end':
> {'dateTime': '2022-01-11T05:00:00-08:00', 'timeZone':
> 'America/Vancouver'}, 'iCalUID': '-@google.com', 'sequence': 0,
> 'reminders': {'useDefault': True}, 'eventType': 'default'}]

Using this for month

```
today = datetime.today()
monthAgo = today - relativedelta(months=1)
tmax = today.isoformat('T') + "Z"
tmin = monthAgo.isoformat('T') + "Z"
events_result = service.events().list(
    calendarId=CAL_ID,
    timeMin=tmin,
    timeMax=tmax,
    maxResults=2500,
    singleEvents=True,
    orderBy='startTime',
).execute()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It should show at least the structure of the event, and example data sets.

Comment: It's from the google calendar v3 api.